# How do I fix "Unhandled rejection TypeError: res.status is not a function" error?

Tags: javascript, express, testing, mocha.js

I have created several endpoints that work fine when testing using the browser and Postman.

I am now writing tests for these endpoints (I know I should have written these tests first) and I keep getting the error -

"Unhandled rejection TypeError: res.status is not a function"

Here is my endpoint code

```
  router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Goal.getAll().then((goals) => {
      res.status(200).json(goals);
    });
  });
```

Goal.getAll() is a function that queries the DB to get the goals.

Here is my test code.

```
describe('API routes', () => {
  beforeEach(() => knex.migrate.rollback()
    .then(() => knex.migrate.latest())
    .then(() => knex.seed.run()));

  afterEach(() => knex.migrate.rollback());

  describe('GET /goals', () => {
    it('should return all goals set', (done) => {
      request(route)
        .get('/')
        .expect(200)
        .expect((res) => {
          expect(res.body[0]).toInclude({
            title: 'blah blah blah',
            description: 'blah blah blah',
          });
        })
        .end(done);
    });
  });
});
```

The test use a test DB. The BeforeEach and AfterEach are there to isolate the different tests I will do.

It would be grateful if someone could help. I don't understand why res.status isn't sen as a function during tests but when I run the server, the endpoints work perfectly.

I tried removing .status but then the error becomes res.json is not a function.

**Update:** I tried creating new files and basic routes and the tests for these also didn't work. The new error I got was " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

**Fixed:** The route was an instance of express Router and it was mounted to the top-level app route. So Instead of importing the single route in test file I needed so import the top level app. Then request the full endpoint. so in my case /api/goals

Comment: What library are you using for `request`?

Comment: Josh, I’m using Supertest

Comment: Can you provide more of the surrounding code? To see what `router` and `route` is and how you import it in your tests. Could you also do `console.log(res)` in your route to see what it actually is during the test? (And how that is different from the normal context.)

Comment: @jotaen. Here is the diff between the two logs of res. - https://www.diffchecker.com/gb9rBUXn

`router` - this is an instance of the express Router 
    `const router = express().Router`
. `route` - I export the route in the goals.js file like so:
    `module.exports = router;`

 and import it into the test like so:
    `const route = require('./goals.js')`

The request is performed by the function `request` from the `Supertest` library. `request(route)`.

Comment: @jotaen. Thanks for your help. I fixed it, see update in main post.